# Saving a plot in minimum number of bytes

Tags: export, pdf-format, fonts, size

I am using both Mathematica 9.0 and 10.0. I found that when I save the following plot

```
a = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\[CapitalDelta]t", 
    Rotate["(\[CapitalDelta]X\!\(\*SubscriptBox[SuperscriptBox[\()\), \
\(2\)], \(AC\)]\)", 0 Degree]}, ImageSize -> 250]
```

in version 9.0 it takes around 1800 kb, while as in version 10.0 it is saved in just 22 kb. The problem is that the FrameLable along y-axis which is $(\Delta X)^2$ gets distorted in version 10.0. In version 9.0 it does not get distorted, but when I save it in 9.0, it takes more space around 1800 kbs.

I save the plot using following `Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "sample.pdf", a]`

Comment: Are you sure that the graphics is saved in the same format? Try `Export["test.jpg",a]` and compare the results for both, mma9.0 and mma10.0.

Comment: How are you saving the plot? Please provide the saving code.

Comment: @Szabolcs Could you update tag usage description for `Save` tag.

Comment: @ercegovac I don't even know why we have that tag. It seems redundant.

Comment: @Szabolcs I agree. Also there are not many questions associated and can be easily removed completely.

Comment: do you specfically want pdf? Edit the question to clarify either way.

Answer (score 2):

AFAICR, in version 10.0 the fonts aren't embedded in the pdf file. That's the reason for the difference in filesize and, most probably, the reason for distorted font letter. Version 9 embeds fonts, but doesn't subsample them, hence the filesize is large. You should upgrade to more recent version which correctly embeds subsampled fonts into PDF. Alternatively you can use a PDF optimizer, for example Acrobat can do it (and the resulting filesize will be almost certainly smaller than recent Mathematica is able to produce).